# How to create something like exponent 'e' or imaginary 'j'

Tags: python, numbers, literals

I have been searching already but I have no idea how those `e` and `j` are called and therefore not found useful information. I am searching for *numbers with chars* for specification or as operators.

Like this exponetial `e` notaion:

```
1e3 = 1 * 10^(3) = 1000
xen = x * 10^(n)            # where x and n are numbers
```

or imaginary numbers with `j`:

```
1 + 3j
```

The benefit I am hoping for is to be able to write `Ppm(2)` (instance of `Ppm` class) conveniently as `2ppm` (where "ppm" is "parts per million" of a frequency in NMR). This can't be thoroughly done with the exponential notation `2e-6` because ppm is referenced to a frequency. Hence it should be distinguished from ordinary numbers.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without modifying Python's source code. Numeric literal syntax like `3j` and `1e3` is effectively hard coded into the parser. Extending the parser to recognize `2ppm` as a literal as well, is beyond the reach of the ordinary user.

Comment: They aren't "called"; they are part of the syntax for floating point and complex numbers. There is no way to extend that to custom classes. Python is not Ruby (although I'm not a Ruby expert, so I can't say if it would be possible there).

Comment: `e` is a [mathematical constant](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#constants); imaginary numbers are [part of the number literal syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#imaginary-literals). Neither is 'called'. You cannot alter Python grammar (at least not at runtime, and you'll have to compile your own Python binary if you tried to change the grammar).

Comment: You can read the language specification, e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating-point-literals, which tells you what literals are acceptable. You would have to create your own fork of Python, with the extra syntax/grammar rules, to make `2ppm` a *"`Ppm` literal"*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think they mean e.g. `1e2`, which is a valid [FP literal](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating-point-literals), rather than the constant.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: right, indeed, I didn't see that the OP is talking about exponents. That's part of the literal syntax too, so the *parser* does the work here.

Comment: I've duped this to an excellent post on adding *statements*, but the same applies to adding expressions or literal notations.

Comment: You might be interested in [Pint](https://pint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) a 'Python package to define, operate and manipulate physical quantities'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, python does not support user defined literals.

Comment: You can get close with `ppm = Ppm(1);   x = 2*ppm`

Comment: @Eric assuming [`Ppm.__rmul__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmul__) is correctly implemented!

Comment: Or with the forbiddenfruit module, `(2).ppm`